# Would like to search for specific word/number inside a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hey guys so i'm pretty new at python and was wondering how I can specifically search for a word/number in Python and its outcome is the row of where that word is from.

staff.txt contains rows of information like

> ID  Name  StartDate  Role
>
> 001 John  1-1-2001 Kitchenhand
>
> 002 Mike  2-1-2001 Cashier

My code so far is this. I'm able to read the txt file, make choices on how to search up a staff through ID or email. I'm just lost on how to code the bit where it searches for the ID inside the txt file. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

````
import random
choices = ["1","2"]
choice2a = random.choice(choices)

#   reads txt file
df = pd.read_csv('staff.txt', 'w', delimiter='\t')

#   deletes Unnamed columns
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]

name= input("How would you like to search for staff?")
print ("1)ID")
print ("2)Email")
choice1 = input("Type Answer")#choice
if choice1 == "1" or choice1 == "1":
  input("Type staff ID")
  ID = ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Read the file into memory with the variable `df` as you are then do something like this

```
# create a function
def myFunc(df):
    # your input
    name = input(f"How would you like to search for staff? \n1) ID\n2) Email\n[1/2]: ")
    if name == '1': # if 1 ask for id input
        ids = input('Type ID number: ') # another input
        return df[df['ID'] == int(ids)] # boolean indexing to return df based on id
    elif name == '2': # if 2 ask for email address
        email =input('Type email address: ') # another input
        return df[df['email'] == email] # boolean indexing to return df based on email address
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'{name} is not 1 or 2') # raise value error if you enter a value other than 1 or 2

myFunc(df) # run the function
```

When run it looks like

```
How would you like to search for staff? 
1) ID
2) Email
[1/2]: 1
Type ID number: 2

   ID   Name    StartDate      Role
1   2   Mike    2-1-2001    Cashier
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using "import pandas as pd" as well. Does this affect anything or can I still use this as a guideline on what I need to do?

Comment: @jvtji you can still use it as a guide the function uses python built-in functions